# Getting processor and system type with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

[image]

My code displays:

```
Hardware information: 
  Processor architecture: x64 (AMD or Intel)
  Number of processors: 8
  Page size: 4096
  Minimum application address: 10000
  Maximum application address: fffeffff
  Active processor mask: 255
  Installed RAM: 32 GB
  Physical Usable RAM: 31 GB
  Current RAM in use: 28%
```

Code:

```
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo{};
GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);

std::map<WORD, CString> mapArchitecture;
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64] = L"x64 (AMD or Intel)";
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM] = L"ARM";
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM64] = L"ARM64";
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64] = L"Intel Itanium-based";
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL] = L"x86";
mapArchitecture[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN] = L"Unknown architecture";

m_strSystemInfo += L"Hardware information: \r\n";
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Processor architecture: %s\r\n", mapArchitecture[siSysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture]);
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Number of processors: %u\r\n", siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors);
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Page size: %u\r\n", siSysInfo.dwPageSize);
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Minimum application address: %lx\r\n", siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Maximum application address: %lx\r\n", siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Active processor mask: %u\r\n", siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask);

ULONGLONG installedMemory{};
if (GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&installedMemory))
{
    m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Installed RAM: %lld GB\r\n", (installedMemory/1024)/1024);

    MEMORYSTATUSEX memstatus{}; memstatus.dwLength = sizeof(memstatus);
    if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memstatus))
    {
        m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Physical Usable RAM: %lld GB\r\n", (((memstatus.ullTotalPhys / 1024) / 1024 / 1024)));
        m_strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Current RAM in use: %d%%\r\n", memstatus.dwMemoryLoad);
    }
}
```

How do we get type processor and system type to be more descriptive, as per Windows About window?

---

I have since learned that `GetNativeSystemInfo(&siNativeSysInfo);` can be used and `siNativeSysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture` will return the bitness of the operating system.

---

This is from CoPilot. Is it right for Win32?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main() {
HRESULT hres;

// Initialize COM
hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize COM library" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// Initialize security
hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,
    -1,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    NULL,
    EOAC_NONE,
    NULL
);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize security" << std::endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

// Obtain the initial locator
IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;
hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,
    0,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWbemLocator,
    (LPVOID*)&pLoc
);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object" << std::endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

// Connect to WMI
IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;
hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    0,
    &pSvc
);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Could not connect to WMI" << std::endl;
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

// Set security levels
hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
    pSvc,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
    RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
    NULL,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    NULL,
    EOAC_NONE
);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Could not set proxy blanket" << std::endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

// Execute the query
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator
);
if (FAILED(hres)) {
    std::cerr << "Query failed" << std::endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

// Retrieve processor information
IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;
while (pEnumerator) {
    hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
    if (uReturn == 0) {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;
    hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
        std::wcout << L"Processor Name: " << vtProp.bstrVal << std::endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
    }

    // Retrieve other properties as needed

    pclsObj->Release();
}

// Cleanup
pSvc->Release();
```

---

I am trying the code in the link provided in the comments. But I am getting compile errors:

```
4>Meeting Schedule AssistantDlg.cpp
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\wbemcli.h(1303,39): error C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol
4>(compiling source file '/Meeting%20Schedule%20AssistantDlg.cpp')
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\rpcndr.h(202,23):
4>could be 'unsigned char byte'
4>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\cstddef(34,24):
4>or       'std::byte'
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\wbemcli.h(1309,45): error C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol
4>(compiling source file '/Meeting%20Schedule%20AssistantDlg.cpp')
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\rpcndr.h(202,23):
4>could be 'unsigned char byte'
4>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\cstddef(34,24):
4>or       'std::byte'
```

To give context, I have put this code as a function in my `CAboutDlg` class which is inline in the main CPP file.

When I double-click the two `byte` warnings it takes me to:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WritePropertyValue( 
   /* [in] */ long lHandle,
   /* [in] */ long lNumBytes,
   /* [size_is][in] */ const byte *aData) = 0;

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ReadPropertyValue( 
   /* [in] */ long lHandle,
   /* [in] */ long lBufferSize,
   /* [out] */ long *plNumBytes,
   /* [length_is][size_is][out] */ byte *aData) = 0;
```

---

Using `_HAS_STD_STYLE=0` and using code in own file it now compiles. But I get error an runtime, here:

[image]

---

I don't understand this code. Why I try for example:

```
        IWbemClassObject* pclsObj;
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
                &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if (0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            VARIANT vtProp{};
            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Architecture", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"Architecture: %d\r\n", vtProp.intVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"AddressWidth", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"Address Width: %d bit\r\n", vtProp.iVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            // Get the value of the Name property
            //hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            //strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"Process Name: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            pclsObj->Release();
            pclsObj = NULL;
        }
```

I end up with:

```
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
Architecture: 0
Address Width: 0 bit
```

Why am I getting all that? I thought it would simply tell me the PC architecture like x86.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor

Comment: @HansPassant How do I use this Win32_Processor class in Visual C++? The linked examples are VB and on the internet I only find C#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example-creating-a-wmi-application

Comment: @HansPassant Question: in my existing InitInstance I have CoInitialize(nullptr) and CoUninitialize in ExitInstance. I notice in your linked article I should use hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);   Will this be a problem? Or just replace my existing line of code with this one?

Comment: That is not a problem, keep what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I have started to understand the principles of how it all works. For example, I can display:

```
Operating System
  Computer Name: HOME-PC
  Edition: Microsoft Windows 11 Home
  Version: 10.0.22631
  Build Number: 22631
  Build Type: 22631
  OS Architecture: 64-bit
  Service Pack Version: 0.0
```

The above is achieved with the following code:

```cpp
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

bool ReadWin32ProcessorInfo(CString &strSystemInfo)
{
    CString strText;

    // Obtain the initial locator to Windows Management
    // on a particular host computer.
    IWbemLocator* pLoc = 0;

    auto hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        strText.Format(L"Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Error code = %d", hres);
        AfxMessageBox(strText, MB_ICONWARNING);
        return false;          // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemServices* pSvc = 0;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with the
    // current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(

        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name
        NULL,                    // User password
        0,                       // Locale
        NULL,                    // Security flags                 
        0,                       // Authority       
        0,                       // Context object
        &pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        strText.Format(L"Could not connect. Error code = %d", hres);
        AfxMessageBox(strText, MB_ICONWARNING);
        pLoc->Release();
        return false;          // Program has failed.
    }

    // Set the IWbemServices proxy so that impersonation
    // of the user (client) occurs.
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(

        pSvc,                         // the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,            // authentication service
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,             // authorization service
        NULL,                         // Server principal name
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,       // authentication level
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // impersonation level
        NULL,                         // client identity 
        EOAC_NONE                     // proxy capabilities     
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        strText.Format(L"Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = %d", hres);
        AfxMessageBox(strText, MB_ICONWARNING);
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }


    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI. 
    // Make requests here:
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumeratorOperatingSystem = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumeratorOperatingSystem);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        strText.Format(L"Query for operating system failed. Error code = %d", hres);
        AfxMessageBox(strText, MB_ICONWARNING);
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }
    else
    {
        IWbemClassObject* pclsObj;
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        strSystemInfo += L"Operating System\r\n";
        while (pEnumeratorOperatingSystem)
        {
            hres = pEnumeratorOperatingSystem->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
                &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if (0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            VARIANT vtProp{};

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"CSName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Computer Name: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Caption", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Edition: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Version", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Version: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"BuildNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Build Number: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"BuildTyoe", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Build Type: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"OSArchitecture", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  OS Architecture: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"ServicePackMajorVersion", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Service Pack Version: %d", vtProp.iVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hres = pclsObj->Get(L"ServicePackMinorVersion", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L".%d\r\n", vtProp.iVal);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            pclsObj->Release();
            pclsObj = NULL;
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumeratorOperatingSystem->Release();
    return true;
}
```

But, even with the above, it differs from the About window. Eg:

[image]

How do we get 23H2 and 22631.3296?

New question?

Comment: This WMI C++ Wrapper class is excellent! https://christophep.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/a-wmi-wrapper-for-c-easy